# Events of more instances of the same custom View

Tags: android

I'm new with Android.
In my project I have the custom View MyView with the follow code

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private final Bitmap baseBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.myImage);
    private final Matrix matrix;
    private boolean active = true;

    public MyView(Context context, Matrix matrix) {
        super(context);
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);   
        if (active) {
            System.out.println("draw "+this.getId());
            canvas.drawBitmap(baseBitmap, matrix, null);
        } else {
        ...
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            System.out.println("--------->"+this.getId());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            this.matrix.setTranslate(event.getX()-(baseBitmap.getWidth()/2), event.getY()-(baseBitmap.getHeight()/2));
            this.invalidate();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            this.active = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In my Activity, I instantiate MyView many times and then add them to the main layout. This is its code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      float cx = display.getWidth() / 2, cy = display.getHeight() / 2;
      int radius = 80;
      double distance = 0, distancePoint = 0;
      final int flags = PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG
            | PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG;
      float length = 0;
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
      Path pathCircle = new Path();
      pathCircle.addCircle(cx, cy, radius, Direction.CW);
      PathMeasure meas = new PathMeasure(pathCircle, false);
      int nObject = 10;
      length = meas.getLength();
      distance = length/nObject;
      int i = 0;        
            while(i<nObject){
                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                meas.getMatrix((float)distancePoint, m, flags);
                MyView myView = new MyView(this, m);
                System.out.println(myView.toString());
                myView.setId(i);
                mainLayout.addView(myView,i);
                i++;
                distancePoint = distance*i;
            }
      }                               
}
```

At runtime, when I touch any MyView element I always get the last. With "`System.out.println("--------->"+this.getId());`" I can see that the id of the touched element is always the last, even if I toch the first or any other element.  Actualy, I just can move the last element.
Does anyone know why can't I get the event of the right istance of MyView touched? 
(I hope my question is clear)
Thanks

---

I changed the code adding the onMeasure method. I used the code of a tutorial, dimensions are not specific for my image. The views are drawn and the result is the same, unfortunately with the same problem. I post the layout xml too, maybe could be useful.

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      float cx = display.getWidth() / 2, cy = display.getHeight() / 2;
      int radius = 80;
      double distance = 0, distancePoint = 0;
      final int flags = PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG
            | PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG;
      float length = 0;
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
      Path pathCircle = new Path();
      pathCircle.addCircle(cx, cy, radius, Direction.CW);
      PathMeasure meas = new PathMeasure(pathCircle, false);
      int nObject = 10;
      length = meas.getLength();
      distance = length/nObject;
      int i = 0;        
            while(i<nObject){
                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                meas.getMatrix((float)distancePoint, m, flags);
                MyView myView = new MyView(this, m);
                System.out.println(myView.toString());
                myView.setId(i);
                nt spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                      myView.measure(spec, spec);
                mainLayout.addView(myView,i);
                i++;
                distancePoint = distance*i;
            }
      }                               
}


public class MyView extends View {

    private final Bitmap baseBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.myImage);
    private final Matrix matrix;
    private boolean active = true;

    public MyView(Context context, Matrix matrix) {
        super(context);
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);   
        if (active) {
            System.out.println("draw "+this.getId());
            canvas.drawBitmap(baseBitmap, matrix, null);
        } else {
        ...
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            System.out.println("--------->"+this.getId());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            this.matrix.setTranslate(event.getX()-(baseBitmap.getWidth()/2), event.getY()-(baseBitmap.getHeight()/2));
            this.invalidate();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            this.active = false;
        }
        return true;
    }


     @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

            int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

            int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
            int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

            int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

            setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
        }

        private int chooseDimension(int mode, int size) {
            if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                return size;
            } else { // (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
                return getPreferredSize();
            } 
        }

        // in case there is no size specified
        private int getPreferredSize() {
            return 300;
        }
}
```

The main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/main_view"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FF66FF33">
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it's because you're basically piling up your views at the top left corner of your `RelativeLayout`. So, only the uppermost (the last one added) is touchable.

I think that if you try adding them to a `LinearLayout`, as a test, you'll see that your view works. Setting `LayoutParams` for a `RelativeLayout` programmatically is not very comfy IMHO.

**EDIT**

I tried your code. The fact is that your views are just made to be drawn one over the other, or else the overall drawing wouldn't come, so my first guess is right (the uppermost covers the others - *even in its transparent parts*)(btw try Hierarchy Viewer and you can see that yourself). So you need to do your job in a single view, or handle the touches like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if(!isPetaloTouched()) {// check if the actual drawing was touched
            return false; // discard the event so that it reaches
                          // the underlying view
        }
//......
```

See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/2cdd4269dfb2772e) for an explanation of how events work in Android.

Both ways would need an `isPetaloTouched()` logic to detect if/which drawing must be moved, but the first would be more efficient of course.

Also, forget about the `onMeasure()` thing, I thought that could help giving the view a size around which to wrap, so that it wouldn't fill its parent and aligning views aside would make sense. However, be sure that the touch would work if the views were not piled up.

(...allora `mPetali` stava proprio per petali!)

Comment: Using LinearLayout I get just the first view, so I tried to use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ,so I tried to use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams as follow
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if(i>0){    
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,i-1);              
            }

            myView.setLayoutParams(params);
      mainLayout.addView(myView,i);
But it still doesn't work.

Comment: @vilandra: in `params.addRule()` you need to pass the view's id (the one you get with `getId()`), not its index as a child of the layout. LinearLayout might have not worked because you forgot to set `android:orientation="vertical"`. However, if it still doesn't work, could you check with Hierarchy Viewer if your view takes up all the space? You might then need to override `onMeasure()` in your custom view.

Comment: @bigstones: No way with LinearLayout and vertical orientation, no way overriding onMeasure(), no way saving the previuos MyView object inside the while and call getId insted of use the index (it's the same thing 'cause I use the index for setId, I suppose). 
I really don't know wich problem could be.
Can be useful to post the code including the onMeasure method?

Comment: @vilandra `(it's the same thing 'cause I use the index for setId, I suppose)` oh sorry, I didn't see that. Yes, please, post that code too, I hope I can help.

Comment: @bigstones: ok, I'm developers shame! The problem now is to know the actual touched View. I made my View implement View.OnTouchListener class, in the View constructor setted `code` this.setOnTouchListener(this)`code` and in the onTouch method (`code` onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) `code`) verified the obtained view. The view is always the current, that is, with my problem, the view passed to onTouch is always the last, so the comparison between `code` v.getId() `code` and `code` this.getId() `code` is always true. In this way, the problem persist. Then, I used a ViewGroup wich ...

Comment: ...draws my custom views and implements OnTouchListener. In the activity I added the viewGroup insted of each View. In the ViewGroup's onTouch method, the passed View id is -1.
(mannaggia, mi era sfuggita una variabile nel refactor! :) )

Comment: @vilandra: the event you get with the listener is just the same you get in `onTouchEvent()`. By `isPetaloTouched()` I mean a method that returns true (to "capture" the event) only if the touch point is a place *where the petal is drawn*. As this can be not easy/efficient, I'd suggest to draw all of the petals in the same view's `onDraw()` with a cycle, and keep the list of their coords to check which ones are close enough to the touched point, then choose the closest. On ACTION_MOVE, you can change its coordinates and call `invalidate()` to redraw.

Comment: @vilandra: se hai altri problemi su questa linea ti consiglio di postare una nuova domanda apposta, riceverai piu' risposte e sara' piu' facile trovarla per gli altri. Poi quando pensi di aver avuto una risposta adeguata puoi accettarla cliccando il segno di spunta di fianco (la cosa da' anche punti di reputazione a te e all'autore della risposta).